# Is a two-point correlation function of two different fields equal to the multiplication of two one-point correlation functions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions

$\phi_i$ is a scalar field with a SO(N) invariant N-fields Lagrangian with $\phi^4$ interactions.
After some calculations I arrived to this result:

For a$\neq$b: $<T \phi_a(x) \phi_b(y) > = <\phi_a(x)><\phi_b(y)>$ 
(For a=b it's just a "normal" two-point correlation function.)

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, and it does. That's what I was trying to prove. And since in this case the vev  of any $\phi_i$ is zero I thought I got it...

Comment: So my result is correct?

Answer (score 1):

After some more study and thinking I found out this is is only true for a free theory (lagrangian only with kinetic and mass term).
If you add interactions your lagrangian is going to have cross terms on the fields:  ( $\phi_1^2$+$\phi_2^2$+...+$\phi_N^2$)^2 , and this leads to a non separable integrand in your path integral, the action will have terms $\phi_a$$\phi_b$... 
To arrive to the result in the question I separated the integrals in $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$, and that is only valid for a theory without cross terms on the fields.

Comment: However, for a$\neq$b  $<T \phi_a(x) \phi_b(y) >=0 $ for both cases!
This can be proved using the fact that $<T \phi_a(x) \phi_b(y) >$ is SO(N) invariant and Schur's Lemma.